# Why cant we use @android:dimen/value or @color/white

Tags: android, xml

Whiling writing a `<style>` in `style.xml`, we access a value in `dimes.xml` by `@dimen/value` VS we access a value in `color.xml` by `@android:color/white`. Why the word "android" in used in case of `color.xml` and not in `dimens.xml`. To be clear: why cant we use `@android:dimen/value` or `@color/white`. Why both values are accessed differently?

Comment: `@android:dimen/value` is inbuild

Comment: Thanks. Where are these inbuild resources stored in the project. Where can i view them

Comment: Check below answer .

Answer (score 0):

If you would CTRL + click on the resource (for instance on @android:color/transparent ) you will see the source code, and the source will show you that the color named *transparent* is defined in the colors.xml file which is under some sdk path:

[image]

That's what the '@android' part does. On the other hand, you can of course use '@color/white', simply defining a resource color names 'white' in your colors xml.

As this is really basic Android, I also suggest you to read about the system a little bit, or you won't understand what you're doing. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks. @Alessio Now i get the big picture.